# Map ADFS Claims to Sharepoint Pofile

Tags: user-profile, authentication, claims-based-auth, user-profile-property

i've set up claims based authentication with SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer using ADFS 2.0 as a backend. Within my ADFS 2.0 i've set up rules to send the LDAP Email as Email, LDAP Surname as Surname and LDAP Given-Name as Name. 
Within SP i've configured everything using Powershell using basicly 3 maps:

```
$map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Email Adresse" –SameAsIncoming
$map2 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Vorname" –SameAsIncoming
$map3 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Nachname" –SameAsIncoming
```

I'm able to login using claims based authentication and the email of the account i'm logging in with (which is used as IdentifierClaim) is displayed within the right top corner of SP. 
Whowever, when i click on "My Settings" to view my current logon profile only the account ( i:05.t|contoso sts|sales.user@contoso.com ) name  ( sales.user@contoso.com ) and email ( sales.user@contoso.com ) are populated with the claims send to Sharepoint. Surname and Given-Name are blank.

Is this a limitation to SP and do i HAVE TO use a custom claims provider to get this mapping done?
I've [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634308/mapping-email-claim-from-custom-claims-provider-to-sharepoint-user-email-in-prof), saying that it is possible to map the claims into the sharepoint profile by simply editing the custom user profile properties. However: it dosn't say how to do so exacly - to be more specific: i think he's talking about the profile sync service which may be linked with a sql database to get additional user profile data. However: i want to map SAML claims provided **WITHIN** the SAML token into the user profile. 
[Looking at this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/what-are-the-claims-supported-by-sharepoint)  it dosn't seem to be possible without a custom claims provider.

Does anybody know it for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge the answer is Yes, you have to create your own custom claims provider for mapping your claims.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699494.aspx