# Alter account display name( i:0#.f|CustomMembershipProvider|) of claims custom membership provider

Tags: 2010, development, powershell, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I found so many solution like replacing the display name of the user manually using PowerShell script `Set-SPuser -identity "User name" -DisplayName "Display Name" -web Web url`.

Since I have more than 1000 user in my site, is there any better way to alter the display name of the user than this?

Comment: You may run a loop over 1000 users and update their DisplayName to be "username".

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: [What are the claims supported by SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/what-are-the-claims-supported-by-sharepoint)

Relevant info:

> If you want to populate the email, display name, etc, in My Settings,
>   configure the User Profile Sync service. Note: there are some
>   additional steps to perform when you use claims-based auth, such as
>   setting the "Claim User Identifier" property.
>
> PS. If you want to see
>   your claims, the code accompanying the following article has a really
>   nice web part that shows all claims with their values:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953202.aspx

Credit to: [Matthieu](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/6357/matthieu)